# XML Post With Json giving Blank Response

Tags: php, json, xml, curl

I am trying to POST XML using CURL but getting empty response 
While the same works here [requestmaker.com](http://requestmaker.com/)

Url : https://ipcharge.net/ipchapi/rh.aspx

XML Code

```
<TRANSACTION>
   <USER_ID>mqueacio</USER_ID>
   <USER_PW>WELcome20</USER_PW>
   <CLIENT_ID>15928200010001</CLIENT_ID>
   <MERCHANTKEY>i6UM7ld85dRsayie8Vh7SPQW3e2s846M2454b4gic5L2ArtOiwsUYgYSYAWDRISL</MERCHANTKEY>
   <FUNCTION_TYPE>PAYMENT</FUNCTION_TYPE>
   <PAYMENT_TYPE>CREDIT</PAYMENT_TYPE>
   <COMMAND>SALE</COMMAND>
   <ACCT_NUM>1111</ACCT_NUM>
   <CUSTOMER_STREET>hgh ghg</CUSTOMER_STREET>
   <CUSTOMER_ZIP>ghgh</CUSTOMER_ZIP>
   <EXP_MONTH>2</EXP_MONTH>
   <EXP_YEAR>2017</EXP_YEAR>
   <PRESENT_FLAG>1</PRESENT_FLAG>
   <INVOICE>123</INVOICE>
   <TRANS_AMOUNT>111.00</TRANS_AMOUNT>
   <CARDHOLDER>HGG HGHG</CARDHOLDER>
   <CVV2>111</CVV2>
</TRANSACTION>
```

Php Code is as follow

```
$ch = curl_init($_POST['url']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST['string']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
$array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)), true);

print_r($array_data);
```

If we put the same data in above website it gives response 
but when I try the same with php its not giving any response

Comment: it seems to me that you json_decode the bad value, try to use this `$array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($output)), true);`

Answer (score 1):

As requesting sending to https server need to pas cert files.. try once by disabling https verification as following.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```